# App not installed Firebase FCM

Tags: android, firebase, sdk, firebase-cloud-messaging

After making a Firebase app and implementing everything I needed, including the .json, gradle, etc. It all compiles fine.

The first time, it said either move to minSdk 23 or use multidex, I chose minSdk 23 for I don't know if that was it. But I am getting app not installed, even though there is no package interference.

It is being built and installed from the mobile IDE "AIDE". If you need any of my code or clarification, please ask. As I haven't had this type of error and I'm assuming I may be missing something. Thank You.

Comment: Hi. Please post the codes you think is relevant. There's a chance for your post to be **put on hold** for lack of details. I guess posting the gradle files would be a start. Any error logs of the sort. Cheers!

Comment: I solved the problem but now I'm getting the error "cannot describe package" J checked the logcat and it seems it is unable to parse the manifest. I'll post the manifest in my question when I get home. in the mean time, do you know any helpful tutorials or anything to add live chat into an app?

Comment: Hi. If you have resolved your issue, please post the answer here. :) Then, if you have a different concern, do post in another question. :)

Comment: I will post the new post, thx

Answer (score 0):

My problem ended up being I accidentally changed the action and category of .MainActivity so it wasn't "MAIN" and "LAUNCHER". Sadly, I did not end up getting the app itself working :(